# How to concatenate netcat data to form a string variable in Bash for email sending?

Tags: linux, string, bash

Concatenate a string in a pipe, while getting data over netcat

I want to collect data over netcat from a specific port. This data should be transferred to another script and should be send via email. I started a pipe with xargs, but got the problem that every single line is send on its own. Now I wanted to concenate a string over the time of the connection and hand this over to the email sending script, but somehow I can't get the string concatenated

```
now = ''
nc -lvp 12345 | $now=$now$1

./ForwardMail.sh $now
```

Could someone help me to concatenate the string?

Comment: What are you trying with `| $now=$now$1`? Assign to `now` with `now=$(nc -lvp 12345)` and use quotes when sending like `./ForwardMail.sh "$now"`.

Comment: do you want to send the entire `nc` output in an email? or do you want to parse out a subset of the `nc` output for sending in an email? if the latter, consider updating the question with a sample set of `nc` output as well as what you want sent in an email

Comment: To reinforce WalterA's comment, `nc ... | $now=$now$1` makes no sense AND is provided solution is what you should be trying. .... Pipes (`|`) are used to send data from the left hand side process to the input on the right hand process. You're sending it to a variable assignment (and a poorly formed one at that, as the `$` at the front of `$now` will be evaluated by the shell as the value currently stored in the variable named `now`.  ... ALSO learn to check your code at https://shellcheck.net . If that doesn't fix it **then** post the corrected code in your question. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

For  a bash script, this is completely nonsense.

The first line

```
now = ''
```

calls a program `now` with two arguments: `=` and an empty string.

You are piping the output of `nc` to a (badly formed) assignment. That makes no sense. By the way: using `$now` on the left side of the `=` is also a bad idea.

Most of these errors wil be flagged by [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net)

From your description, I get the impression that you want to do:

```
netcat=$(nc -lvp 12345)
./ForwardMail.sh "$netcat $1"
```

But even that seems strange. Possibly,

```
netcat=$(nc -lvp 12345|ts)
```

would be a better idea.

Ofcourse, we've no idea what `ForwardMail.sh` looks like, and what it does with different lines as argument.